# Cannot use GPIO pins for output

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, netbeans-8

I'm trying to light an LED through Java, but when I run my project, I receive this message in the output:

```
wiringPiSetup: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied
Unable to change ownership of /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value: Operation not permitted
Unable to change ownership of /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/edge: Operation not permitted
```

How do I get access to use GPIO pins?

**Program:**

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;

public class HelloRPi 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
         System.out.println("Program started...");

        // create gpio controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        final GpioPinDigitalOutput pin = 
                gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_07, "REDLED", PinState.HIGH);

        System.out.println("--> GPIO state should be: ON");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // turn off gpio pin 
        pin.low();
        System.out.println("--> GPIO state should be: OFF");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        pin.toggle();
        System.out.println("--> GPIO state should be: ON");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // toggle the current state of gpio pin  (should turn off)
        pin.toggle();
        System.out.println("--> GPIO state should be: OFF");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println("--> GPIO state should be: ON for only 1 second");
        pin.pulse(1000, true); // set second argument to 'true' use a blocking call

        gpio.shutdown();
    }      
}
```

**SETUP (RPi B+):
(3v3)**

- Redwire: GPIO 7 and 30d
- LED: (pos) 30e and (neg) 29e
- Resistor: 29d and 29b
- GND: pin 9 and 29a

Comment: Do you run as `root` user ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Ok, Now I have root@raspberrypi: in PuTTy and navigated to my jar file. When I ran it in NB, The same error appears, but when I ran it the commandline on PuTTY, the program ran without errors, but no light (led) came on.

Comment: I had to use the Pi4J diagram instead of the canakit diagram. Now lights are showings